# old datepicker is displayed in android 4.3

Tags: android, datepicker, android-dialog, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I have made an android activity in that i have used android default datepicker dialog,I am running it i am getting old type datepicker of android version,as i have attached in picture below,I want the latest version of date picker as display in second scree,[image: old datepicker in android 4.3]

[image: Android 4.3 datepicker actual]

**code**

```
    DestAdapter adapter;
    public static final String[] MONTHS = { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May",
            "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" };

    private Calendar cal;
    private int dy;
    private int month;
    private int year;
    int flag = 0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_book);
tv_from.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                flag = 1;
                showDialog(0);
            }
        });
}
@Override
    @Deprecated
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, year, month, dy);
    }

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
            if (flag == 1) {
                tv_from.setText(selectedYear + "/" + selectedMonth + "/"
                        + selectedDay);
            } else if (flag == 2) {
                tv_to.setText(selectedYear + "/" + selectedMonth + "/"
                        + selectedDay);
            }

        }
    };


}
```

**manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.eps.blancatours"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: post manifest and project.properties here

Comment: in which device you tested?

Comment: @RanjitPati- samsung galaxy grand2

Comment: have you tested in any other device ?

Comment: @RanjitPati-yep,but thing is that i have used same code in other app and gettign new datePicker...so get weired..!!! :(

Comment: @RanjitPati-its my splash screen,It is not involved with this.i just have posted manifest to show min and max target version

Comment: @user3820044 I think this is an unfortunate problem. As I saw everything is fine. i can only suggest to change the `minSdkVersion` from 8 to 14 and clean your project. then check once again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

go into manifest file and find the activity name in which your datepicker code is present 
and give latest theme to that activity using `android:theme` properties inside `<activity>` tag

your code is perfect there is no bug or no any error in it you are using old theme thats why it is looking like this . now just change it to newer theme and you will get your result

newer theme in the sense the theme which supports for newer version and who shows the date picker in the manner which you want
use

```
Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_NoActionBar in activity tab of manifest file
```

or you can pass theme into date picker there is constructor of date picker who accept the theme

```
    DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_NoActionBar, 
new DateListener(v), mTime.year, mTime.month, mTime.monthDay);
```

Comment: your's the perfect solution,thank you..:) but i am having problem but can you tell how to set  theme to spinner as well to display latest one.thanks in advance

Comment: http://www.mokasocial.com/2011/03/easily-create-a-default-custom-styled-spinner-android/

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution for this,actually i have set my activity theme as below,Which is not supported in other api levels,

```
  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

I have changed it,and got desired solution...